# Outputting to excel document with array and using NumberFormat

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am outputting large sets of data, to excel. I am using writing each column to a range of cells using arrays.

```
Dim startCell As Excel.Range = xlsWorksheet.Cells(2, intCol)
Dim endCell As Excel.Range = xlsWorksheet.Cells(strData.GetLength(0) + 1, intCol)
Dim writeRange As Excel.Range = xlsWorksheet.Range(startCell, endCell)
writeRange.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
writeRange.Value = strData
```

The problem I am having is that the NumberFormat isn't applying properly. When I open the document, none of the numeric cells are properly formatted. However, the formatting is part of the document. If enter a individual cell in excel and then press enter, the formatting will apply to the data.

I had this issue before when I was outputting the data to excel with a loop over each cell and I would apply the formatting after outputting the data. I found that if I moved the formatting before outputting the data this solved the problem in that situation. I have tried doing the formatting before and after output and get the exact same results.

Comment: Odd code, hard to believe it is real.  My crystal ball says that you'll be ahead when you actually assign a number instead of a string.

Comment: Your solution worked, although it was a bit more difficult to implement since the actual code was a lot more complicated (different datatypes for different columns). Also excel apparently doesn't like decimal values, but since the numbers were small enough I just cast as double since precision wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The issue may be to insert the data first then set the format. Excel may be making up a format at insert time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting the array to be a numeric datatype. Also decimal datatype wouldn't work with excel, I cast them as double and assigned to a double array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NumberFormat` in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is very simple. The code below is tested and working:

```
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xl.Visible = True

    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    ws = wb.Sheets.Add()
    ws.Name = "TEST SHEET"

    ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Test Value"
    ws.Cells(3, 2) = "1.234567"
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 2), ws.Cells(3, 2)).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

Results:  
[image: results]

"0.00%" as the `NumberFormat` will produce a percentage value with two digits of precision.